# What is this wire in switch for?

Tags: wiring, switch, voltage

So I’m working on an arduino project for switching my light with it, but in my switch, there are 2 cables (if I count in/out as one) and I don’t know what the second is. When I meassure voltage between one and two while the switch is off the voltage is 230V as expected. When I meassure the voltage between the cable 3 and 2 (while the switch is off) I get like 9V of AC. And even when I completely cut off the powet from this switch I read about 5V of AC. What is that brown cable for? (Cable 1 is in and 2 is out) I’m from Czech Republic if it might help.

[image: Photo of the switch]

Comment: Given the voltages, it might a floating (unconnected) wire. Those 9V could easily be just random noise induced in the wire. Can you post a photo of the inside/back of the box, so that we see the cables entering the box before they split up into wires?

Comment: There is nothing much to see inside. These 3 cables just go into hole in top. If you still want to see the picture I can send it, but I think its unnecesary to disasemble the switch again.

Comment: If that is indeed the case, it would mean this was wired in a very _unorthodox_ way that has nothing to do with applicable regulations. Better to stay away from it then. There's no cable type in Czechia which would have black-black-brown conductors, so either there have to be two cables (with more conductors not seen in this photo), or these are just loose wires in conduit (that plastic pipe which gets put into walls to run wires in), but then there has to be another box (perhaps above this one, close to the ceiling) where that conduit ends.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with AC mains power.  It is dangerous stuff that is really outside the range of electronics hobbyists.  Particularly, no homebrew electronics should ever be **wired** to AC mains.

The only contact your projects should have with mains is through commercially sold low voltage power supplies, which are approved by your government's consumer protection apparatus.  Such things are cheap commodities and one should never accept a second-rate knockoff via mail order.

So.  How do we control lights with an Arduino?  Wirelessly.

Install a commercially made, *approved*, smart switch that provides wireles control, according to its instructions.  Use the appropriate Arduino accessory, such as WiFi, to talk a protocol the switch understands.  That's it.  One option is the classic X10 powerline signaling, but you will need an X10 WiFi gateway product to convert the WiFi to X10.

Comment: Well my problem with comertialy made things is that either you switch it with physical switch or with the wifi switch. Or atleast I don’t know about variant that can be switched off with physical switch and then turned on with wifi. Im open to ideas

Comment: Shelly switches do what you ask.

Comment: @krystof18 "How can I use approved AC mains side equipment to control switches via WiFi" is not a hard problem, it's more of a shopping question, which is not our bailiwick here.  Last I looked at Shelly, it was the typical cheap Chinese with a fake CE (self-certification) mark.  Maybe they put some of their profits into some actual 3rd party lab certification.